# How to detect my Intel graphics chipset?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

I recently bought an HP 15-r022TX notebook with NVIDIA GeForce 820M card. I installed Windows 7 Pro 64-bit and headed over to NVIDIA's webite to download drivers for my card. When the installation begins, the setup prompts me to first install an Intel driver first.

[image]

So I headed over to [Intel Download Center](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx) but whenever I use [Intel® Driver Update Utility](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect), IE stops responding. Now I have to download the drivers manually. But I do not know which Intel graphics driver I have. How do I know that?

[Here](http://www.flipkart.com/hp-15-r022tx-notebook-4th-gen-ci5-8gb-1tb-free-dos-2gb-graph-j6m27pa/p/itmdx8pkgz6k7dnx?pid=COMDX8PAFEWHBXS6&otracker=from-search&srno=p_1&query=hp%2015-r022tx&ref=ecf8ef00-28a7-46a6-b7b7-a3b754c7f69d) are the laptop specs.
Here's the screenshot of 'Right click on desktop' -> 'Screen resolution' -> Advanced settings' -

[image]

Comment: You don't need an exact graphics model, there's only a handful of drivers that each support many different chips.  See https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=23162&lang=eng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=7280191)’s your model’s support site. It’s the very first result on Google. It would be unusual if no such thing existed, considering how the device has all the latest hardware.

All the necessary drivers, including drivers for both Intel HD Graphics and NVIDIA Graphics, are available there.

If you don’t trust HP, you could’ve easily acquired the driver on Intel’s site [just by browsing to it](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=deu&ProdId=3719). Auto-detection always sucks. Don’t ever use it, especially if you have the specs available.

Oh yeah, as for the “how?” and “what Intel GPU?”: [It’s properly documented, of course.](http://ark.intel.com/products/81016/Intel-Core-i5-4210U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_70-GHz?q=%204210U)

Comment: Thanks for the laptop support link. I tried finding the model from HP's website, but for some reason I couldn't find it. Also, when I called HP support, they said they don't provide support for this model anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Intel chipset (motherboard) drivers before installing any other drivers. It may be graphics. Download the drivers from HP's official site. Select your model and you will find all the drivers related to your motherboard.